# Compiling SWC file from FDT

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, fdt

I've made a library which I'd like to compile to an SWC file, I've tried to do this in FDT by choosing FDT AS3 Library as Run settings, but all I end up with is a 0kb .swc file. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I can't find much when I google it either, if anybody has a quick walkthrough on how to do it saved in your bookmarks or something, that would be great!

Many thanks,
Will

Comment: I stopped using FDT because it's full of bugs like this. Best of luck to you -- even though I no longer get code hints/refactoring/etc, I'm still a faster, better coder with a plain text editor plus a command line than I was dealing with FDT's problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download the flex sdx and compile swc's with compc (component compiler). The command would look something like:

```
path_to_flex_sdk\bin\compc -source-path source_path -output output_path\my_swc.swc -include-classes DocumentClass
```

replacing *path_to_flex_sdk* with the path to wherever you installed the sdk, *source_path* with the path to your source code, *output_path* with wherever you want the swc placed, and *DocumentClass* with the name of your document class (which should be in the directory specified by source_path).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add sources manually in SWC Launcher configuration, Compiler arguments tab:

```
-include-sources={project}/src
```